# Copy one column value to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, cursor

I have a table that has the following values

```
 sno     package  id
 66      250     111
 66       0      100
 66       0      99
 66       0      88
 67      270     225
 67      267     111
 67      0       35
 68      230     111
 68      225     250
 68      0       210
```

Now what I want is where the value of package is 0 put that value of package where id is 111 ie for 66: 250, for 67: 267, for 68: 230

the following result

```
sno    value     id    
66     250      111
66     250      100
66     250      99
66     250      88
67     270      225
67     267      111
67     267      35  
68     230      111
68     225      250
68     230      230
68     230      210
```

I am applying some of the queries like

```
select sno, case age when 0 then (select age from table1 where id=111 )
                     else 1 end as age, ID from table1
```

This internal subquery gives more than one value, also I cannot do it as hardcode using sno.
How it can be done?. Please help using `groupby clause` or some `joins` or `cursor`.

Thanks

Comment: For descending IDs per sno, are lower values always zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think of this as "looking up" age in the table, when the age is 0.  For this, I would structure the query as:

```
select sno, (case when t.age = 0 then lookup.age else t.age end) as age, id
from table1 t left outer join
     (select *
      from t
      where id = 111
     ) lookup
     on t.sno = lookup.sno;
```

The `left outer join` is to ensure that no rows are lost if there is no "111" row.  The subquery is to be clear about the logic in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT sno
      , CASE WHEN age = 0 
             THEN (SELECT age FROM table1 t1 
                    WHERE t1.id=111
                      AND t1.sno = t2.sno ) 
             ELSE age END AS age
      ,ID 
FROM table1 t2
```

Or you can also use self join for the same (I think this is better):

```
SELECT t1.sno
       , CASE WHEN t1.age = 0 
              THEN t2.age 
              ELSE t1.age END AS age
      ,t1.ID 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
  ON t1.sno = t2.sno
 AND t2.id=111;
```

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════╦═════╗
║ SNO ║ AGE ║ ID  ║
╠═════╬═════╬═════╣
║  66 ║ 250 ║ 111 ║
║  66 ║ 250 ║ 100 ║
║  66 ║ 250 ║  99 ║
║  66 ║ 250 ║  88 ║
║  66 ║ 250 ║  87 ║
║  67 ║ 270 ║ 225 ║
║  67 ║ 267 ║ 111 ║
║  67 ║ 267 ║  35 ║
║  68 ║ 230 ║ 111 ║
║  68 ║ 225 ║ 250 ║
║  68 ║ 230 ║ 230 ║
╚═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58e0c/12)